# numpy.where() clause error

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Briefly... here is the problem:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 100, 8, 9])
np.where(a==100, -1, a[a])
```

What I expect to get is:  `0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, -1, 8, 9`
Instead I'm getting: `index 100 out of bounds 0<=index<10`

I admit that the index is invalid but is shouldn't eval a[100] but -1 instead... as far as I understand numpy.where() command structure.

What I'm doing wrong in this example?

Just to clarify what I actually trying to do here is more detailed code:
It is a lookup table array remapping procedure:

```
import numpy as np

# gamma-ed look-up table array
lut = np.power(np.linspace(0, 1, 32), 1/2.44)*255.0

def gamma(x):
    ln = (len(lut)-1)
    idx = np.uint8(x*ln)
    frac = x*ln - idx
    return np.where( frac == 0.0,
                    lut[idx],
                    lut[idx]+(lut[idx+1]-lut[idx])*frac)

# some linear values array to remap
lin = np.linspace(0, 1, 64)

# final look-up remap
gamma_lin = gamma(lin)
```

Comment: you should avoid using the same a with different meanings, even in different scopes (a[a] is really ugly and bad). also, a==100 is your condition that's why it gets evalued http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: Yes, i agree that my quick code was not the best example. In my actual code (check above) I do not have such thing as `a[a]` but anyway getting `index out of bound` because python always validates (executes?) both expressions within `numpy.where` clause call.

Answer (score 2):

Expressions that you put as function arguments are evaluated before they are passed to the function ([Documentation link](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#calls)). Thus you are getting an index error from the expression `a[a]` even before `np.where` is called.

Comment: Thanks silvado, the doc reference explains this issue. I'm a python beginner so not quite aware of all the function call pequliarities.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
np.where(a==100, -1, a)
```

As stated by the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
numpy.where(condition[, x, y])

Return elements, either from x or y, depending on condition.
If only condition is given, return condition.nonzero().
```

Here, `a==100` is your condition, `-1` the value that should be taken when the condition is met (`True`), `a` the values to fall back on.

---

The reason why you're getting an IndexError is your `a[a]`: you're indexing the array `a` by itself, which is then equivalent to `a[[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,100,8,9]]`: that fails because `a` has less than 100 elements...

---

Another approach is:

```
a_copy = a.copy()
a_copy[a==100] = -1
```

(replace `a_copy` by `a` if you want to change it in place)

Comment: still this works fine: a = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 100, 8, 9 ]
a = [ -1 if k==100 else a[k] for j, k in enumerate(a)] which is handled just fine by python... but I see where my problem is, thanks. Still not quite undertand why it is necessary to evaluate two expressions if only one is used after all.

Comment: @decuman: with `a = [ -1 if k==100 else a[k] for j, k in enumerate(a)] ` you never get to evaluate `a[k]` when `k=100`, therefore you don't run into the IndexError.

Comment: I see. I've just confused python's `if` conditional execution with `numpy.where()` functional call specific.

Answer (score 0):

When you write `a[a]` you try to take index 0,1,2...100... from `a` which is why you get the index out of bounds error.  You should instead write `np.where(a==100, -1, a)` - I think that will produce the result you are looking for.